# How to create "unallocated space" on my disk to install ubuntu onto?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, hard-drive, 20.04, disk-usage

[This is my disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOrFb.png)
[My file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7OKr.png)

I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto the 500 GB HDD (E:) (Disk 2). There is 96 GB of free space on this drive which is where i want to install Ubuntu but when i try install it, it only lists 3.34 GB free space on Disk 1. I now realise i need to create unallocated space on Disk 2 but i'm not sure how to. I've tried shrinking the volume through disk management but an error appears - [The volume you have selected to shrink may be corrupted. Use Chkdsk to fix the corruption problem, and then try to shrink the volume again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54YxA.png). I then did check disk and this was the result - [It said windows has scanned the file system and found no problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0AcR.png). So i'm not sure what to do now as i keep trying to shrink the volume but the same error appears but i'm not even sure this is the correct way to create unallocated space so i would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to consult with Windows documentation and Windows support to modify your Windows installation to make room for Ubuntu.  We can't advice on what to do when your problem right now is exclusively within the Windows operating system and drives used exclusively by Windows. I suggest researching/asking on SuperUser how to shrink your Windows partitions if you are having difficulty.

Comment: The Windows utility obviously does not work properly, as it states Disk might be corrupt, but the same OS says that it did not find issues, and an endless cycle, right @Santan? I do not see a windows issue here, I see someone trying to create one. I am also proposing a different approach, which done right will not cause data loss.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do that by:

- booting a live Ubuntu Mate
- there I start `sudo gparted`
- I would be very careful which disk I edit, and shrink the existing partition so that it still has plenty of free space, so out of those 96Gb I would cut out 64Gb.. and still have 30Gb which Windows can use.
- Once I lower the size of the 500Gb partiton, I would create a new partition thee `ext4` with a rough size of 60Gb, and the rest I would create as `swap`.
- Once that is done, I would apply the changes, Note that this might take time, as at this time Gparted is moving any files that have been wriiten at the disk to relocate them... so it can safely resize it..
- If all goes without issues, I would close gparted, and run the GUI Installer from Ubuntu, and when it asks me which partition to use as `/` I would choose that specific `60Gb newly created partition`. Swap partition should be automatically recognized. You should not touch or mount any of the existing other partitions, unless you know what you are doing... they will be available after the installation is done.
- And once the installation finishes, Ubuntu will have created a dual boot grub menu, where you will be able to boot to Windows, or to Ubuntu.

Once again, be VERY careful which partition you shrink, and which one you choose for your Linux installation..

Comment: Why Ubuntu MATE?  This is not the flavor that OP is wanting to install.  OP already has installation media for Ubuntu.  And Disks is ridiculously easier to use for someone who is struggling with this kind of tasks

Comment: @Nmath Ubuntu Mate was an example. How do you know which flavor is the OP wanting exactly?  He only mentions Ubuntu.. This was my opinion. If you have a better one, add another Answer..

Comment: The Ubuntu i tried to install was 20.04.1 LTS. Sorry i forgot to mention that, i'm not sure if that is the flavour you are mentioning but knowing this do you think i should use Mate or Disks? Also i'm not familiar with the code like 'swap', 'ext4' and 'sudo gparted' so if you could explain that it would be great.